# Refreshing OSGI application-context

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, applicationcontext

I'm developing OSGI application and I need to refresh my application-context.xml during runtime.

I wanted to use

```
String ctxPath = ....
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(ctxPath);
((ConfigurableApplicationContext)ctx).refresh();
```

The problem is - I can't find a way to get path to my application-context.xml (its inside OSGI bundle). The only way I'm aware of, to get inside files of bundle, is to use

```
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/application-context.xml"));
```

But I can't get path from `InputStream`. Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: How does your bundle look like at the moment? Are you using spring-dm to start spring in OSGi?

Comment: What do you mean by "how your bundle look like" exactly? And No, I'm not using spring-dm

Comment: So how do you start spring inside your bundle? Using an Activator?

Comment: afaik osgi bundle resources cannot be used as files on file system. you may want to use a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` instead of  `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`; and provide the path "/application-context.xml".

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine is to get the `InputStream` (you could also you the [`Bundle.getEntry` for that](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#getEntry(java.lang.String))) and then save the the file somewhere you would know the path. I have seen this approach in several applications so I assume it is correct.